# How to load image in Kotlin Compose desktop?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

How to load images from the hard disk when using Kotlin compose on the desktop?

Comment: I'm trying to figuring out how to load from a url...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get ImageAsset with this function

```
fun imageFromFile(file: File): ImageAsset {
    return org.jetbrains.skia.Image.makeFromEncoded(file.readBytes()).asImageAsset()
}
```

**Full example:**

```
import androidx.compose.desktop.Window
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageAsset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.asImageAsset
import java.io.File

fun main() = Window {
   val file = File("D:\\images\\my_image.PNG")
   val image = remember { imageFromFile(file) }

   Image(asset = image)
}

fun imageFromFile(file: File): ImageAsset {
   return org.jetbrains.skia.Image.makeFromEncoded(file.readBytes()).asImageAsset()
}
```

Comment: It's skia, not skija

Answer (score 15):

other answers are outdated, as per Compose 1.0.0-beta5 you should do the following:

`Image(painterResource("image.jpg"))`

if you want to load a bitmap only

`val bitmap = useResource("image.jpg") { loadImageBitmap(it) }`

Only the file name is required (not full path), but make sure that your resources are in `src/main/resources/image.jpg`

Answer (score 5):

Try this one:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.BitmapPainter
import androidx.compose.ui.res.loadImageBitmap
import java.io.File


val file = File(path)
val imageBitmap: ImageBitmap = remember(file) {
    loadImageBitmap(file.inputStream())
}

Image(
    painter = BitmapPainter(image = imageBitmap),
    contentDescription = null
)
```

Comment: This is the simplest and best answer. Other answers rely on 3rd part libraries or only work for images defined as resources.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```
 Image(bitmap = imageFromResource("image.png"),
       "image",
 )
```

`contentDescription` is necessary, but can be anything you'd like. You can also add modifiers such as

```
val imageModifier = Modifier
   .height(240.dp)
   .fillMaxWidth()
   .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))

Image(bitmap = imageFromResource("header.png"),
      "image",
      imageModifier,
      contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Image.asImageBitmap() is deprecated. Use new Image.toComposeImageBitmap(). For now (01.04.2022) it's not deprecated yet:

```
@Composable
fun CanvasArea2() {
    val image = remember { imageFromFile(File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/banana.png")) }

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF))) {
        drawImage(image)
    }
}

fun imageFromFile(file: File): ImageBitmap {
    return org.jetbrains.skia.Image.makeFromEncoded(file.readBytes()).toComposeImageBitmap()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

from the docs : [Loading images from device storage or network asynchronously](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Image_And_Icons_Manipulations#loading-images-from-device-storage-or-network-asynchronously)

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.produceState
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.BitmapPainter
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.rememberVectorPainter
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.res.loadImageBitmap
import androidx.compose.ui.res.loadSvgPainter
import androidx.compose.ui.res.loadXmlImageVector
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.singleWindowApplication
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import org.xml.sax.InputSource
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import java.net.URL

fun main() = singleWindowApplication {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    Column {
        AsyncImage(
            load = { loadImageBitmap(File("sample.png")) },
            painterFor = { remember { BitmapPainter(it) } },
            contentDescription = "Sample",
            modifier = Modifier.width(200.dp)
        )
        AsyncImage(
            load = { loadSvgPainter("https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/raw/master/artwork/idea-logo.svg", density) },
            painterFor = { it },
            contentDescription = "Idea logo",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
            modifier = Modifier.width(200.dp)
        )
        AsyncImage(
            load = { loadXmlImageVector(File("compose-logo.xml"), density) },
            painterFor = { rememberVectorPainter(it) },
            contentDescription = "Compose logo",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
            modifier = Modifier.width(200.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun <T> AsyncImage(
    load: suspend () -> T,
    painterFor: @Composable (T) -> Painter,
    contentDescription: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
) {
    val image: T? by produceState<T?>(null) {
        value = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                load()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                // instead of printing to console, you can also write this to log,
                // or show some error placeholder
                e.printStackTrace()
                null
            }
        }
    }

    if (image != null) {
        Image(
            painter = painterFor(image!!),
            contentDescription = contentDescription,
            contentScale = contentScale,
            modifier = modifier
        )
    }
}

/* Loading from file with java.io API */

fun loadImageBitmap(file: File): ImageBitmap =
    file.inputStream().buffered().use(::loadImageBitmap)

fun loadSvgPainter(file: File, density: Density): Painter =
    file.inputStream().buffered().use { loadSvgPainter(it, density) }

fun loadXmlImageVector(file: File, density: Density): ImageVector =
    file.inputStream().buffered().use { loadXmlImageVector(InputSource(it), density) }

/* Loading from network with java.net API */

fun loadImageBitmap(url: String): ImageBitmap =
    URL(url).openStream().buffered().use(::loadImageBitmap)

fun loadSvgPainter(url: String, density: Density): Painter =
    URL(url).openStream().buffered().use { loadSvgPainter(it, density) }

fun loadXmlImageVector(url: String, density: Density): ImageVector =
    URL(url).openStream().buffered().use { loadXmlImageVector(InputSource(it), density) }

/* Loading from network with Ktor client API (https://ktor.io/docs/client.html). */

/*

suspend fun loadImageBitmap(url: String): ImageBitmap =
    urlStream(url).use(::loadImageBitmap)

suspend fun loadSvgPainter(url: String, density: Density): Painter =
    urlStream(url).use { loadSvgPainter(it, density) }

suspend fun loadXmlImageVector(url: String, density: Density): ImageVector =
    urlStream(url).use { loadXmlImageVector(InputSource(it), density) }

@OptIn(KtorExperimentalAPI::class)
private suspend fun urlStream(url: String) = HttpClient(CIO).use {
    ByteArrayInputStream(it.get(url))
}

 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Using compose-1.1.0, this works for me.

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.skia.Image
// ...
Image(
    contentDescription = "image",
    bitmap = Image.Companion.makeFromEncoded(imageBytes).toComposeImageBitmap()
)
```